# How to Get a custom header value from an HttpAuthenticationContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I am busy implementing and Authentication filter:

```
public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var request = context.Request;

        // Receive token from the client. Here is the example when token is in header:
        var token = request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Token").Value.ToString();   //["Token"];
```

How do I get the header called token ? Because the above code doesn't work. I am guessing this is because its not a standard header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
request.Headers.GetValues("token");
```

Comment: Wait, this is the answer? Doesn't this return an IEnumerable?

Comment: You could use the following if you expect one value:

var token = request.Headers.GetValues("token").FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

You should actually use

```
request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
```

Comment: And what is the reason why this should be used over the other answer?